# How to create a relation with an ID inside a Type

Tags: mongodb, prisma

By using prisma, I want to create a relation between two models, UserWorkspace and Plan.

I'm working with an already created database so i can't modify its structure.

The problem I'm facing is that the UserWorkspace Model has a field defined by a Type that contains the planId, in the UserWorkspace Model i want to define the relation by using the ID inside the type.

```
type UserWorkspacesSubscription {
  date_end   DateTime? @db.Date
  date_start DateTime? @db.Date
  planId     String?   @map("plan") @db.ObjectId
}

model UserWorkspace {
  id           String                      @id @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  subscription UserWorkspacesSubscription?
  Exams        Exam[]
  Plan         Plan?                       @relation(fields: [subscription.planId], references: [id])

  @@map("user_workspaces")
}

model Plan {
  id               String          @id @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  UserWorkspaces   UserWorkspace[]

  @@map("plans")
}
```

But this line gives me an error: `@relation(fields: [subscription.planId], references: [id])`

`Error validating: The argument fields must refer only to existing fields. The following fields do not exist in this model: subscription.planId`

How can i solve this?

I tried moving the relation in the type but that is not a valid action for prisma

Answer (score -1):

The issue with the @relation directive is that it can only be used to create a relation between top-level fields of a model, and not fields nested inside a complex type like UserWorkspacesSubscription.

One way to work around this limitation is to manually create a foreign key constraint in your database between the UserWorkspace.subscription.planId field and the Plan.id field. Then, you can create a computed property in the UserWorkspace model that gets the corresponding Plan object based on the planId field. Here's an example of what the UserWorkspace model would look like with this approach:

```
type UserWorkspace {
  id           String                      @id @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  subscription UserWorkspacesSubscription?
  Exams        Exam[]
  planId       String?                     @map("subscription.planId")
  plan         Plan?                       @ignore // we'll define a resolver to get this field
  @@map("user_workspaces")
}

model Plan {
  id               String          @id @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  UserWorkspaces   UserWorkspace[]

  @@map("plans")
}
```

Note that we've added a new field planId to the UserWorkspace model that maps to the nested subscription.planId field. We've also added the @ignore directive to the plan field, since we'll define a resolver for it manually.

Next, we can define a resolver for the plan field that fetches the Plan object based on the planId field:

```
extend type UserWorkspace {
  plan: Plan
    @resolve(
      fields: ["planId"]
    )
    async (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
      if (!parent.planId) {
        // if there's no planId, return null
        return null
      }

      const plan = await ctx.prisma.plan.findUnique({
        where: { id: parent.planId }
      })

      return plan
    }
}
```

This resolver uses the @resolve directive to specify that it should run when either the planId field or the plan field is requested. It then fetches the Plan object based on the planId field, and returns it.

With this approach, you can still use the plan field in your queries just like any other field, but its value will be computed based on the planId field and the Plan object fetched from the database.